# Would increasing the load resistance in a buck converter increase efficiency?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck

I was recently asked in an interview if the efficiency of a buck converter would change based on changing the load resistance (I assumed this meant constant input and output voltage).

I answered that it would be a positive correlation, as you increase load resistance your efficiency would also increase since the losses caused by passive components would be less.

Was this the correct line of thinking? Or was my logic wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

> *Would increasing the load resistance in a buck converter increase
> efficiency?*

Unlikely. The losses in a buck converter will be fairly predictable across a wide range of loads especially if a synchronous buck were used. This means that it's more likely that the power conversion efficiency will reduce as load resistance increases. Think about when the load resistance is infinite i.e. no load current. There is no output power and hence, power efficiency has to be zero.

As you lowered the load resistance (from infinity), the output takes power and therefore efficiency rises as load current rises. At some point this will turn around but this will be close to full load current. Near full-load current efficiency is likely to fall as load current increases more.

If you look at the data sheets of many, many buck converters (such as the [LT8619](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt8619-8619-5.pdf)) you will see efficiency vs load graphs and these will pretty much reflect what I have written: -

[image]

Only when the load current is above around 500 mA does the efficiency fall as load current increases but, look at the efficiency below load currents of about 1 mA; efficiency drops off rapidly as load current falls. Of course, there will be exceptions where efficiency stays pretty good from full load down to some lower value but, in the main, for the devices I have used, power conversion efficiency generally falls as load current falls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the question asked is formulated as you have written that is,

"*Would increasing the load resistance in a buck converter **increase efficiency**?*"

Also assuming that **increase efficiency** refers to increasing the step-down (buck) converter efficiency then the answer is simple increasing the load resistance has no effect on the buck converter efficiency.

Reason is that the load resistor is a seperate entity from the converter system.

To justify this claim recall what a buck converter looks like [Power Electronics Daniel by W. Hart].

[image]

The basic elements that make up the buck converter are the diode, inductor, and capacitor where the load resistor is required for system performance demonstration and the input voltage source for exciting the system.

The system of interest is the converter itself which is made up of the diode, inductor, and capacitor we will assume that these three circuit elements are ideal. Efficiency of a system is usually determined by comparing the power output over power input.

In the illustration above the power input is P_s = (V_s)(I_s) and power output is P_o = (V_o)(I_R).

If the converter is lossless (no power loss in the diode, inductor, or capacitor) then theoretically power input is equal to power output that is P_s = P_o.

If where to then compute the efficiency of the converter that is P_o/P_s and where given that P_s = P_o then you would find 100% efficiency (in practice this is difficult to achieve but the efficiency should be close to 100%).

Returning back to the question "*Would increasing the load resistance in a buck converter increase efficiency?*" the **answer is it will not**.

To wrap things up lets us suppose that the load resistance increases, what happens?

Recall that the task of a buck converter is to produces a lower average output voltage than the DC input voltage. As such if the load is increased (zero to infinity), the outputted DC voltage should remain constant (assuming the duty cycle, inductor and capacitor magnitudes are fixed). Given now, that voltage output is kept constant and load resistance is increased the output current (current flowing through the resistor) will decrease according to Ohm’s Law.

Computing the power output you will find that the power output will be equal to the power input (assuming a lossless converter) even though in practice the power output will always be slightly less than the power input.

Hopefully this explains the reason for why "*Would increasing the load resistance in a buck converter increase efficiency?*" **will not have any effect**.